# IE-8 iframe and flash object ignores z-index?

Tags: flash, iframe, internet-explorer-8, z-index, swfobject

I have the following divs and I'm trying to make the iframe layer infront of my_flash. 
It's a common problem and I've read through all the solutions I could find and still I'm getting issues in IE8. I'm using SWFobject by the way.

Here's the source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("index.swf", "my_flash", "100%", "100%", "8.0.0");
swffit.fit("my_flash",900,650);
</script>

<div id="my_flash" style="z-index:1;"></div>

<div  style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px; z-index:9999; position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 110px;" >
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?blah.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"  style="z-index:9998"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, z-index does not affect Flash Player. See this example: http://demos.learnswfobject.com/html-over-swf/dynamic.html (Related [tutorial](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/placing-html-elements-over-a-flash-movie/))

In the example linked above, the parent element has `position:"relative"`, and the HTML element has `position:"absolute"`. The SWF doesn't need to have `position` specified. None of the elements has `z-index` specified. The SWF needs to have `wmode` set to either `opaque` or `transparent`. `wmode:"opaque"` is preferred to `wmode:"transparent"` as `transparent` is known to cause issues and use much more processing power than `opaque`.

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
/* establish relationship with child elements */
#wrapper { position: relative; }

/* this element will automatically appear overtop 
   of the wmode=opaque SWF without needing z-index */
#myiframe { position: absolute; }

/* No CSS needs to be specified for the SWF */
#myswf { }
</style>

<div id="wrapper"> 
    <iframe id="myiframe" src="mypage.html"></iframe> 
    <div id="myswf">This will be replaced by SWFObject</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the wmode parameter of the Flash object when embedding with SWFObject.

[Here](http://nooshu.com/swfobject-2-2-and-wmode-transparent) is a short tutorial to do that.

Here is a modified code for your problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  swfobject.embedSWF("index.swf", "my_flash", "100%", "100%", "8.0.0", null, { wmode: "transparent" });
  swffit.fit("my_flash",900,650);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
params.wmode = "transparent";
var attributes = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("index.swf", "my_flash", "100%", "100%", "8.0.0", '/swfobject/expressInstall.swf',
    flashvars, params, attributes);
```