# IE Z-Index issues

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe

I am having the classic problem, my header navigation bar is going under my iframe in the body, but my attempt at solving this with z-indexes has just left me more confused and still with the same problem :/
Here is my setup:

```
<header style="z-index:2;">
....code....
<nav align="center" style="z-index:2;">
....nav....
</nav>
</header>
<section id="content" style="z-index:-1;">
<div class="block">
    <div class="main">
    <!--[if IE]>
<div style="z-index:-2;">
<iframe width="900" height="900" style="position:relative; z-index:-2;" src="http://www.flytheflagtexas.com/athens/magazine/latest/index.html" ></iframe>
</div>
<![endif]-->
....code....
```

Why wont the z-index:-2 iframe appear under anything?
Here is the page: http://www.flytheflagtexas.com/athens/latest feel free to go through the code

Comment: Perhaps repeat question of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242034/ie-8-iframe-and-flash-object-ignores-z-index

Comment: z-indexes are relative only to containers. your `-1` is in a different block than the `2`

Comment: how do I make the header block appear over the section block then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index works only if you have given used positions for laying out the components. Otherwise it just doesn't work. This means that z-index Applies to: positioned elements

Comment: @HemenAshodia: You should give position to your  parent div of iframe. btw king posted the question and where did you try the solution.

Comment: on his website i made changes in my computer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#nav{position:relative; z-index:2;}
```

and for the frame

```
#content{position:relative;}
```

You don't need to give a z-index value to the bottom element, but you can, just make it less then 2.

Answer (score 0):

Z-index only works reliably when you use

```
position: relative;
```

or

```
position: absolute;
```

If you don't set position in CSS to one of the supported values, z-index won't have any effect.