# Iframe always on top in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe, z-index

I have some page content in an iframe. I also have a drop-down menu that contains some user options. In IE (9), when I open the drop-down the menu, it appears behind the iframe. In every other browser, the behaviour as is correct (the menu appears on top of the iframe).

I have tried applying various z-index properties to these elements without success. Their common parent element is just a `<body>` tag.

How can I ensure that the drop-down always appears on top of the iframe in IE?

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242034/ie-8-iframe-and-flash-object-ignores-z-index - you should find the answer there.

Comment: That question seems very specific to SWF objects. The solution involves passing wmode to the flash object, which doesn't apply to the iframe.

Comment: can you share a fiddle of your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one possible solution is to put an empty iframe on the screen, directly beneath the drop-down menu. You can use the z-index in this context to ensure that menu appears overtop of your empty iframe, and the whole thing will appear on top of the original iframe.

Not a very nice solution, but it works. I'm open to any suggestions on how to do this in a nicer way.